# How to speed up Xpath performance in SQL Server when searching for an element with specific text

Tags: sql-server, performance, xpath

I am supposed to remove whole rows and part of XML-documents from a table with an XML column based on a specific value in the XML column. However the table contains millions of rows and gets locked when I perform the operation. Currently it will take almost a week to clean it up, and the system is too critical to be taken offline for so long.

Are there any ways to optimize the xpath expressions in this script:

```
declare @slutdato datetime = '2012-03-01 00:00:00.000'
declare @startdato datetime = '2000-02-01 00:00:00.000'
declare @lev varchar(20) = 'suppliername'
declare @todelete varchar(10) = '~~~~~~~~~~'

CREATE TABLE #ids (selId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)
INSERT into #ids
select id from dbo.proevesvar
WHERE leverandoer = @lev
and proevedato <= @slutdato
and proevedato >= @startdato


begin transaction  /* delete whole rows */
delete from dbo.proevesvar
where id in (select selId from #ids)
and ProeveSvarXml.exist('/LaboratoryReport/LaboratoryResults/Result[Value=sql:variable(''@todelete'')]') = 1
and Proevesvarxml.exist('/LaboratoryReport/LaboratoryResults/Result[Value!=sql:variable(''@todelete'')]') = 0

commit
go

begin transaction /* delete single results */
UPDATE dbo.proevesvar SET ProeveSvarXml.modify('delete /LaboratoryReport/LaboratoryResults/Result[Value=sql:variable(''@todelete'')]')
where id in (select selId from #ids)
commit
go
```

The table definitions is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProeveSvar](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CPRnr] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [ProeveDato] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ProeveSvarXml] [xml] NOT NULL,
    [Leverandoer] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Proevenr] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Lokationsnr] [nchar](13) NOT NULL,
    [Modtaget] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_ProeveSvar] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [IX_ProeveSvar_1] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [CPRnr] ASC,
    [Lokationsnr] ASC,
    [Proevenr] ASC,
    [ProeveDato] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The first insert statement is very fast. I believe I can handle the locking by committing 50 rows at a time, so other requests can be handled in between my transactions.
The total number of rows for this supplier is about 5.5 million and the total rowcount in the table is around 13 million.

Comment: You need to show us the definition of the [proevesvar] table, including any indexes and keys, as well as how many rows it has.  Some sample data would help too.

Comment: also, how long does the first step (the INSERT) take and how many rows does it return?

Comment: Sorry for the late followup. Email-notifications were off. They are on now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not really used xpath within SQL server before, but something which stands out is that you're doing lots of reads and writes in the same command (in the second statement). If possible, change your queries to..

```
CREATE TABLE #ids (selId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)
INSERT into #ids
select id from dbo.proevesvar
WHERE leverandoer = @lev
and proevedato <= @slutdato
and proevedato >= @startdato
and ProeveSvarXml.exist('/LaboratoryReport/LaboratoryResults/Result[Value=sql:variable(''@todelete'')]') = 1
and Proevesvarxml.exist('/LaboratoryReport/LaboratoryResults/Result[Value!=sql:variable(''@todelete'')]') = 0


begin transaction  /* delete whole rows */
delete from dbo.proevesvar
where id in (select selId from #ids)
```

This means that the first query will only create the new temporary table, and not write anything back, which will take slightly longer than your original, but the key thing is that your second query will ONLY be deleting records based on what's in your temporary table.

What you'll probably find is because it's deleting records, it's constantly re-building indices, and causing the reads to also be slower.

I'd also delete/disable any indices/constraints that don't actually help your query run.

Also, you're creating your clustered primary key on the ID, which isn't always the best thing to do. Especially if you're doing lots of date scans.

Can you also view the estimated execution plan for the top query, it would be interesting to see the order in which it checks the conditions. If it's doing the date first, then that's fine, but if it's doing the xpath before it checks the date, you might have to separte it into 3 queries, or add a new clustered index on 'proevedato,id'. This should force the query to only run the xpath for records which actually match the date.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. The temp-table is used for both the delete and modify statements. According to the execution-plan the time consuming part is the xml-reading above all, and the delete statements does not read any indexes. I tried your suggestion on my test-db and its run time was improved with 10 percent. However it made me think of another improvement - move the first exists clause to the temp-table query so it is not run twice. This improved performance with 50%. The final script will be split in batches of 100 rows to avoid downtime because of locking.